# Launch agent via execution of command on the master options not found in jenkins Slave Setup

Tags: jenkins, ssh-agent, jenkins-agent, launch-agent

I was using Jenkins 1.7.4 version in RHEL Linux server. I can able to configure the slave using "launch agent via execution of command on the master" option during slave setup.[image]

Now we have upgraded jenkins to 2.121.1 version. Now we unable to find that option in the upgraded version.

[image]

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Manually I Installed command-launcher, jdk-tools plugin. Then it works.